# Float image left, fit parent, keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I have the following: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/axtawaLk/6/)

What I'm trying to do is have the image float left of the text such that it fills the parent (`.box`). Note that the `.box` can vary in height depending on the number of lines of text.

The end result should look like this: [image: i.imgur.com]

How would this be done?

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.img {
  float: left;
}
.text {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="text">This box is one line.</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="text">This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is **no HTML/CSS only solution** to make this work - correct me if I'm wrong. The OP wants to have an **image with unknown size dynamically scaled to the parent's container's height**. This container on the other hand depends dynamically on the text length and has no fixed height. The image size can vary, the text size can vary.

Here a **proof of concept** solution using jQuery and `<img>` instead of `background-image` with the following result:
[image: image scaled to boxes]
HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <img class="img" data-src='https://placehold.it/500x500'>
  <div class="text">This box is one line.</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript / jQuery

```
var $boxes = $('.box');
var $imgs = $boxes.find('.img');
for (var i = 0; i < $boxes.length; i++) {
  var heightParent = $boxes.eq(i).outerHeight() - 4; 
  // -4 because of border 2px top + 2px bottom
  $imgs.eq(i).attr('src', $imgs.eq(i).attr('data-src'));
  $imgs.eq(i).height(heightParent);
}
```

CSS (only changed part):

```
.img {
  float:left;
  margin-left: -24px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

It's not such a trivial thing to achieve what you want as you don't want to set height. Not on the image and not on the parent container.

**Problems using background-image:**
With the `background-image` approach it would easy be possible to position the image correctly scaled to the left with `position:absolute`, but the margin to the right (to the text) would not work, as the width can be different.

**Problems using img:**
On the other side with the use of `<img>` you have the problem, that the parent `<div>` will always be in the original height of the image, as long as no parent has a fixed height - which is the case in your example.

**JavaScript for partly making it work:**
To avoid this you can avoid the creation of the image on page load by setting the url to a `data` attribute, I called it `data-src`. Now when the page is load, you can look for the parent's `<div>` *natural* height. Next you pass the URL from the `data-src` attribute to the `src` attribute so that the image is rendered.
As we know the former parent's height we can set it as the image height.

The CSS negative margins are there to *undo* your setting of `padding: 24px` on the parent's container so that the image is correctly positioned. If you ask yourself why I subtract 4 from the height - this is because you want your image to be **within** the border, so we need to subtract the 2px to the top + the 2px to the bottom of your border.

Note: Of course this solution would not work responsive without further scripting, but your parent `<div>` seems not to be responsive anyway.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/av9pk5kv/

**Problems with the layout wish and the above example:**
You could argue that the **wished layout** is **not worth aspiring to** in the first place, it will not work with more amount of text if you don't change something else. At some point there is so much text, so that it's just impossible to place the image filling the parent:
[image: problem with two many lines]
To avoid it partly you would have to remove the fixed width of the parent.
But the same (or similar) result will happen if the dynamically including of the image via JavaScript leads to more text lines as there were before (the text is squeezed).

**How would I solve these problems:** I'd use another layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` on the parent element and `display: table-cell` on the children.

[<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/Xg597MNMfZVBcjF2uFW2/)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    figure {
      display: table;
      width: 600px;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 24px;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    img {
      float: left;
      display: table-cell;
      min-height: 100%;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    figcaption {
      font-size: 14px;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MhHgEb1.png">
    <figcaption>This box is one line.</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MhHgEb1.png">
    <figcaption>This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines. This box has two lines.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice idea to use table layouts! But there's still the problem that the images are not scaled as the OP wanted. It's just outputting the images in their original sizes.

Comment: Responsive? I missed that part. since the container is a fixed width and there's a large amount of wall to wall padding.

Comment: No his code seems not to be responsive because of the fixed width, right. No I meant have a look at the OP's image. He wants one and the same image to be scaled depending on the text in the container. It should not be of the same size

Comment: OIC, so shrinkwrap around the text not the image.